# Inheriting a Security Group From Itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have multiple EC2 instances in a security group and I want to ensure that all other EC2 instances can access any of the other in the same Security Group.

If I try do this, I get a circular reference error:

```
    "XYZSecurityGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "VpcId": {
      "Fn::ImportValue": {
        "Fn::Sub": "${NetworkStackName}-VPCID"
      }
    },
    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
      {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "80",
        "ToPort": "80"
      },
      {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "27017",
        "ToPort": "27017",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {"Ref": "XYZSecurityGroup"}
      }
```

Creating a separate SecurityGroupIngress element seems to overwrite my existing settings. So how can I enable all instances in the same security group to see each other? I also want this Security Group to accept traffic from another security group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow every instance in the same Security Group to share any data between each other at Cloud Formation JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781255/allow-every-instance-in-the-same-security-group-to-share-any-data-between-each-o)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html), you can use the [`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-security-group-egress.html) and [`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html) resources to define self-referencing security group rules:

> **Important**
>
> If you want to cross-reference two security groups in the ingress and egress rules of those security groups, use the `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress` and `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress` resources to define your rules. Do not use the embedded ingress and egress rules in the `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`. If you do, it causes a circular dependency, which AWS CloudFormation doesn't allow.